# $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_{n})=0$ implies $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(X1_{A_{n}})=0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the next:

Let $X\in\mathcal{L}^{1}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P).$ Suppose that $A_{n}$ be a sequence of events such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_{n})=0.$ Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(X1_{A_{n}})=0.$

I'm stuck prove it. I was thinking a way to use an inequality that involves $P(A_{n})$ as superior bound of $E(X),$ which is finite because $X\in\mathcal{L}^{1}$ ($\mathcal{L}^{1},$ denotes the set of all integrable functions) but I don't get any useful. I think Monotone Convergence Theorem, Dominated Convergence Theorem and Fatou Lemma can't be applied.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0.$

Since $X\in L^{1}$ by dominated convergence there is $M>0$ such that 
$E(|X|1_{|X|>M})<\epsilon.$

So, 
\begin{align*} 
E(|X|1_{A_{n}})  &\leq E(X 1_{|X|\leq M} 1_{A_{n}} ) +\epsilon\\
&\leq  ME( 1_{A_{n}} ) +\epsilon
\end{align*}

Taking $\limsup $ the previous yields
$$\limsup _n E(|X|1_{A_{n}})<\epsilon$$
for all $\epsilon >0$

Therefore,
$$\limsup _n E(|X|1_{A_{n}})=0.$$
which concludes the problem.

Comment: Why can you apply dominated convergence @clark?

Comment: @Squird37 Because $X\in L^1$, $X<\infty$ almost surely

Comment: But I don't get why $E(|X|1_{|X|>M})<\epsilon.$ @clark

Comment: Pick $\omega$ then $|X|(\omega) = C$ so when $M>C$ $|X|(\omega) 1_{|X| >M} (\omega)=0$, so $|X|1_{|X| >M}\rightarrow 0$ when $M\rightarrow \infty$ almost surely. And $|X|(\omega) 1_{|X| >M}  \leq |X|$. So we can apply dominated convergence

Comment: Wow!! Many thanks @clark. Now all is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\mathbb{E}(X1_{A_n})=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}(X1_{A_n}|1_{A_n})\right)$

Hint 2 (other way): Note that $|X1_{An}|\leq |X|$ (with probability 1)

Comment: But It could be that if $\omega\in A_{n}^{c},$ $X(\omega)<0$, isn'it? @Martín Vacas Vignolo

Comment: @Squird37 yes, with modulo.